# Many connections in state, How I can prevent this more # number

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, configuration, centos6, apache-2.4

Please, by this command I can know the number of connections for each IP:
`netstat -plan|grep :80|awk {'print $5'}|cut -d: -f 1|sort|uniq -c|sort -nk 1`

Sometimes greatly increase the number of contact for each IP 
I want a way to determine this number for each IP ? 
For example, no more than 20 contact ?

CentOS 6.6 
Apache 2.4

Thanks.

Comment: to clarify: did you want to limit outpu to only IPs with under 20 connections ?

Comment: Exactly .... Yes

Comment: Droopy4096, I don't want to display these IP, I want limit connections, no more than 20 or 30 connections  each IP

Comment: You should also consider turning on Keepalives in httpd (disabled by default in EL-based distributions, although I believe the upstream default is to have it turned on.) You may well wish to reduce the KeepaliveTimeout value to a small value however.

Another strategy you can employ to reduce connections from the same IP, is to make proper use of caching (particularly using `Cache-Control: public max-age=XXX s-maxage=YYY`) and making your site cache-friendly. That Cache-Control header will help to get browsers using its browser cache without having to validate content.

Answer (score 0):

Now with the changed topic, this becomes a question for iptables.

What I currently use (in overly simplified form) is:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j LOG --log-prefix "DoS Filter(connlimit): "
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j DROP
```

obviously you may want to plug above into your iptables rules in appropriate spot and perhaps use `-A` instead of `-I`. Please consult [iptables manual](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) (connlimit and tcp modules in particular ) for more info